Solutions to install flexplot R are not working
I cant install flexplot in R and the solutions offered in similar posts are not working. I have tried:
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot")
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot")
devtools::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot", ref="development")


This produces errors like:
Using GitHub PAT from the git credential store.
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
HTTP error 401.
Bad credentials
Rate limit remaining: 55/60
I am using R 4.4.1 and Rstudio  2024.04.2+764 (2024.04.2+764) on MacOS 14.6.1 (23G93) Intel processor

See also the tips at https://happygitwithr.com/https-pat.html?q=credential#pat-troubleshooting for removing old, invalid personal access tokens.

I am sorry but I dont even no what those are, that is too technical for me

Well, at some point you must have followed a guide to setup github integration via personal access tokens. Try running install.packages("gitcreds") then gitcreds::gitcreds_delete().

Ok, I have no idea what that means but after I used your code I got: 1: Abort update with error, and keep the existing credentials
2: Delete these credentials
3: See the password / token (this than shows a long kind of pasword I am not sure if this is save to delete?

Since you seem to have no idea what it is or what it was used for, it seems safe to delete.

Ok it seems to have something to do with an old github account I have (but not actively use). Does this affect the github account?

@MrFlick It worked! I have flexplot up and running! Awesome, thank you soo much
